# Finding a convergent sequence in a defined metric space

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

For $ p \in [1, \infty )$ we denote by $h^p$ the metric space:

$h^p = \left \{ a \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \mid \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |a(n)|^p < \infty             \right \}$

with the distance $d_p$ given by:

$d_p(a,b) = \left \| a-b \right \|_p = \sqrt[p]{\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|a(n)-b(n)|^p}$

I'm trying to prove that $ h^p ⊂ h^q $   if $1≤p≤q≤∞ $

Then I need to find an $ A \in (h^1)^{\mathbb{N}} $ which converges in $h^{\infty}$ but not in $h^1$

I'm having a lot of difficulty with this question, and haven't come close to thinking of a solution, though I was told it had something to do with defining $[A(k)](n)$ for $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$ for finding the $A$

Any help with this questions would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the fourth line you're summing over $n\in\mathbb{N}$, I suppose? Also, it is $[1, \infty)$, not $[1,\infty]$.

Comment: @Iwanttomakegames and @ Gregory The "infinity norm", $\|a\|_\infty$, returns the maximum absolute value of an entry in the sequence.  As such, $h^\infty$ (or as I'm more used to notating it as, $\ell^\infty$) is the space of bounded sequences.

Comment: For the second part, think about the sequence of sequences, $(1,0,0,\dots), (1,1,0,0,\dots), (1,1,1,0,\dots),\dots$

Comment: Yes, well spotted! Sorry for any confusion. It should be $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and also $ n \in \mathbb{N}$. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p\geq 1$. If $a$ is a sequence in $h^p$, then 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n\geq 0} \vert a(n) \vert ^p <+\infty
\end{equation*}
which implies $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\vert a(n) \vert ^p=0$, which implies that, there is a certain $N$ such that, for all $n>N$, $\vert a(n) \vert ^p<1$. Let now $q>p$, then for all $n>N$, we have $\vert a(n) \vert ^q<\vert a(n) \vert^p<1$. Then we deduce 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n\geq N}\vert a(n) \vert ^q<\sum_{n\geq N}\vert a(n)\vert ^p<+\infty 
\end{equation*}
and since 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n< N}\vert a(n) \vert ^q
\end{equation*}
is finite since it is a sum of a finite amount of positive terms $\vert a(n) \vert ^q$, we conclude 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n\geq 0} \vert a(n) \vert ^q <+\infty
\end{equation*}
that is, $a\in h^q$

For the second part of the question, you can consider the sequence $b(n)=1/n$, and define a sequence $A(k)(n)$ which is related to $b(n)$